# Как обработать произвольное количество аргументов?

Tags: bash

Задание: написать bash скрипт для выполнения команды cp. Этот код работает только для 2 файлов. Как сделать так, что бы можно было вводить любое количество файлов?

```
file1=""
file2=""
if test 3 -eq $#
then
 echo cp $1 $2 $3
 cp $1 $2 $3
```

Comment: Этот код вообще не работает. Вы забыли `fi`.

Comment: Вот полный код
file1=""
file2=""
if test 3 -eq $#
then
 echo cp $1 $2 $3
 cp $1 $2 $3
esle
 echo "from: "
 read file1
 echo "to: "
 read file2
 echo cp $file1 $file2
 cp $file1 $file2
fi
Вторая часть работает как нужно, а первая часть работает только для 2-x файлов.Нужно, чтобы можно было вводить любое количество файлов.

Comment: Добавте из комментария прямо вопрос кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/980611/edit).

Answer (score 0):

весь список аргументов передаётся в переменной `$@`. для передачи его другой команде лучше заключить эту переменную в двойные кавычки — тогда составные аргументы, состоящие из двух и более слов, разделённых пробелами, и помещённых в кавычки, тоже будут переданы помещёнными в кавычки.

```
cp "$@"
```